# Failed to open file for inclusion

Tags: php, include, dir

I keep getting this error

`Failed opening '/php/php_includes/easyCMSv2.php' for inclusion` the file is from my admin panel that I am writing. The admin panel is located in a subdomain, and I need to reach back to `public_html`, so I do

```
include_once('../../../php/php_includes/configurate.php');
```

Yet I get the error for some inclusion. I am just trying to add files my directory looks something like this

```
 --public_html
   --css
   --php
     --php_includes
     --css
     --templates
   --js
   --administrator(sub-domain)
     --admin
     --{dynamic encoded path}
       --login.php 
       --testheader.php
```

login.php needs to include files from the directory `php`

I have been trying everything, yet I am missing more than hitting. Any words of advice from the wise. I'm tired of trying to work on this one little issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the structure you posted you have too many step ups in your directory list. In cases like yours I always used

```
echo get_include_path();
```

with a good chance it is pointing to some totally different folder other than public_html.

Comment: What the heck is this ? .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

Comment: it is your linux include path. if you have an index.php file in your public_html folder you can add a line there set_include_path('');. That will set your include path to the public html directory. Than you can do include_once('php/php_includes/configurate.php')

Comment: Yeah I was reading it from the PHP.net site just then. Do I have to set this for every page?

Comment: I you have object oriented code and possibly an autoloader somewhere, or every request goes through your index.php file, than setting it once there is enough. I will remain the same.

Comment: Ok so I tried your method of just quotes and it is still the linux path. So I am going to try a couple methods I suppos

Comment: You can try it like include_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'php/php_includes/configurate.php'. This way include path is not taken into account. You are referencing according to the current file location. Review the folder structue, but it should be something like this.

Comment: Did not work also `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` didn't as well. I believe 000webhost is messing with something here to prevent me from accurately doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Going up two levels in the directory hierarchy is enough:

```
include_once('../../php/php_includes/configurate.php');
```

Comment: Let me try, I've been trying every stage of hierarchy, though I won't put it past myself that I forgot something minor myself.